# Evertime I boot up my kali linux on usb my files get deleted

Tags: files, boot, kali-linux, usb-drive

ive installed kali linux on my usb drive so the problem is that every time I boot up the system my files get deleted for example- suppose I've created a folder and when i reboot or shutdown my system the folder is gone. Ive tried everything but it dosent seems to work

Comment: That's because it doesn't have persistence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a feature of Kali linux, not a bug. If you would like to keep things saved, the keyword you are looking for is "persistence". Here is Kali's official guide for adding persistence to a USB stick. https://www.kali.org/docs/usb/kali-linux-live-usb-persistence/

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create files on the same media you use to boot up from. No persistence.
You need to create it in other drive.

Comment: You don't need another drive, you can add persistence on the same USB drive.

Comment: Good to know, thanks for the information!